# Is there any way to find which one of multiple timers raised exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

```
import asyncio
from aiohttp import Timeout


async def main():
    try:
        with Timeout(1) as t1:
            with Timeout(1) as t2:
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as exc:        

        # Which one of timers raised this `exc`?
        # Something like:

        # get_caller(exc) is t1 -> False
        # get_caller(exc) is t2 -> True

        pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Since both timers have same timeout, both of them can raise `TimeoutError`. I want to know which one did it. Is it possible?

Comment: Wouldn't you be able to give each a try-except block? Then just print in the exception whether it was 1 or 2 that gave it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
async def main_async():
    try:
        with NamedTimeout('outer', 0.5) as t1:
            with NamedTimeout('inner', 0.3) as t2:
                await asyncio.sleep(2)
    except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
        print(e.timeout_name)

class NamedTimeout(Timeout):
    def __init__(self, name, timeout, *, loop=None):
        super().__init__(timeout, loop=loop)
        self.name = name

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        try:
            super().__exit__(exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError as e:
            e.timeout_name = self.name
            raise
```

If you vary the timeout values you will see it always prints out the name of the shorter timeout.